# Queue of same integers

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a queue of integers with same value following one another in array and I should be using either ArrayList or List, the problem is that the usage of ArrayList is pretty much useless in my code, could you please help me out how to make my code simpler ?

- to make it clear why I need this - it's school homework

For instance if the given array is gonna be `5,5,5,3,2`
ArrayList should contain `5,5,5`
If the array is gonna be `5,5,3,3`
The teacher doesnt seem to care if there's gonna be `5,5` in the list or `3,3`

My code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class UlohaA6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int arr[] = new int[sc.nextInt()];
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i]=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    sc.close();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = 0;
    int xmax = 0;
    int imax = 0;
    boolean first = true;
    for(int i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(i<arr.length-1)
            if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]){
                if(first==true){
                    x++;
                    first=false;
                }
                x++;
                if(x>xmax){
                    xmax=x;
                    imax=i+1;
                }
            }
            else{
                first=true;
                x=0;
            }
    }
    System.out.println(imax);
    System.out.println(xmax);
    if(xmax!=0&&imax!=0)
        for(int i = imax+1-xmax;i<=imax;i++)
            list.add(arr[i]);
    System.out.println(list.toString());
    sc.close();
}

}
```

Comment: `"the problem is that the usage of ArrayList is pretty much useless in my code,..."` -- why do you say this? What specifically is worrying you? `"could you please help me out how to make my code simpler"` -- simpler in what way? Again what is your most *specific* concern?

Comment: So, the basic theory would run along something like, if the current value is equal to the last value, then you should add them to the list. Once the current value is no longer equal to the next value, you can break out of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> could you please help me out how to make my code simpler ?

Well, that's not really what SO is for and since your code works, I'm kind of wondering what the question really is.

The important part of your problem is "understanding" how the solution works.  If you can understand the "solution", then there are any number of ways it might be made simpler, in fact, much of my own work is "understanding" the solution to a problem before I try and reduce it and clean it up ... and sometimes, if it works, just leave it alone.

However, if you want to "simplify" the solution, first, you should start with trying to "visualise" the problem, so, assuming an `input` of `{5, 5, 5, 3, 2}`, we could loop through through the values, starting at `1` and testing the "current" value against the "previous" value and it might look something like this...

```
+=======+==================+==============+=======+
| index | input[index - 1] | input[index] | match |
+=======+==================+==============+=======+
|     1 |                5 |            5 | true  |
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
|     2 |                5 |            5 | true  |
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
|     3 |                5 |            3 | false |
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
| ....
```

This is a basic representation of a `for-loop`

Why start at `1`? Well, you could start at `0` and test against the current and next values, but you'd still need to take into account the possibility of overflowing the end of the array, this is just a simple way of avoiding that problem.

But, what does that look like in code?

Well, it "might" look something like this...

```
int[] input = new int[]{5, 5, 5, 3, 2};
List<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>(input.length);
for (int index = 1; index < input.length; index++) {
    if (input[index] == input[index - 1]) {
        // We've not added the first element yet
        if (matches.isEmpty()) {
            matches.add(input[index]);
        }
        matches.add(input[index]);
    } else {
        // No point going forward
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

The trick here is, getting the "first" element into the `List`, as when we do our first match, nothing is in there.  There are a few ways you might do this, this is just one.

What about capturing all the groups?  Well, that becomes a little more complicated, as you need a better way to manage the various `List`s and know when you need to discard one and create a new one, but, it might look something like...

```
int[] input = new int[]{5, 5, 5, 3, 3};
List<List<Integer>> allMatches = new ArrayList<>(5);
List<Integer> matches = null;
for (int index = 1; index < input.length; index++) {
    if (input[index] == input[index - 1]) {
        if (matches == null) {
            matches = new ArrayList<Integer>(input.length);
            // We need the previous value
            matches.add(input[index]);
        }
        matches.add(input[index]);
    } else {
        if (matches != null) {
            allMatches.add(matches);
        }
        matches = null;
    }
}
if (matches != null) {
    allMatches.add(matches);
}
System.out.println(allMatches);
```

In reality, this is just taking your two loops and reducing them into one.

Comment: Thx man, that's exactly what I needed to see :D - how to reduce my code even if it's a little thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the code to be cleaner and more readable.
Also, I removed the list, because it has no functionality but for printing, so I created the output myself. You can still use the List if you prefer, and then you don't need the last part which is basically building a output string similar to your output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int arr[] = new int[sc.nextInt()];
    sc.close();
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i]=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    // The current number sequence
    int currentNumber = -1;
    // The current number of occurrences of the sequence
    int occurs = 0;
    // The maximum occurrences of a sequence
    int maxOccurs = 0;
    // The number that occurrences the most
    int maxNumber = -1;

    // Running on all of the array items and find the maximum sequence
    for (int currItem : arr) {
        // If the sequence was changed
        if (currItem != currentNumber) {
            // Check if the sequence that just ended is bigger than the biggest right now
            if (maxOccurs < occurs) {
                maxOccurs = occurs;
                maxNumber = currentNumber;
            }

            // Anyway, reset the occurrences number and current number
            occurs = 1;
            currentNumber = currItem;

        // If the sequence was NOT changed
        } else {
            // Increment the occurrences
            occurs++;
        }
    }

    // Check if the sequence that just ended is bigger than the biggest right now again - maybe it is at the end of the array
    if (maxOccurs < occurs) {
        maxOccurs = occurs;
        maxNumber = currentNumber;
    }

    // Create the output string. Note - I did it only to match the output of your list 
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < maxOccurs; i++) {
        output.append(maxNumber);

        if (i < maxOccurs - 1) {
            output.append(",");
        }
    }

    output.append("]");

    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

Cheers,
Golan

Comment: Thx, for ur help